# Avoid Query String that appears in the address bar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have applied a filter on a page using drop downs.

When i click on apply filter.. the page gets filtered.
Now i click on the edit of filtered result.. which redirects me to another page.

I want to send the selected data from the drop downs from the filter page to the redirected page.. and again to the filter page.. to retain the filter.
I am doing all this by sending the values in Query string.

Is there anyway.. i can avoid the visibility of the query string in the address bar and still get the values and required result.

Answer (score 2):

Well to be honest, querystring *is* the correct persistence mechanism in this particular scenario.

I would stick with QueryString. If you don't want to clutter the URL, pass through identifiers (codes, for example), that you could map to in code.

Of course if you are hell bent on not using querystring, you could use Session.

Comment: can u elaborate more on passing through identifiers.. i dint get u there??

Comment: just a code, instead of the entire value. e.g if you were passing through "foo.aspx?selectIndex=someSpecialValue", it looks bad - so you could pass through "foo.aspx?s=1212", where "s" would map to "selectIndex" and "1212" would map to a particular value that could be selected. It's nothing special, just shortening the URL.

Answer (score 1):

only two possible ways: 
1. Use encoded data in the query string (This will not hide data in query string, but data will be in unreadable format for others)
2. Use session to send data to next page